# ember-rails parent child dropdown, computed property?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I have 2 Ember.Select drop downs. One has **categories** and the other has **subcategories**. I want to filter the **subcategories** on the basis of the value selected in the **categories** dropdown. The values for both the dropdowns are populated from an API call to rails code initially.

Categories and subcategories have a has_many, belongs_to relationship.

A jsFiddle example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer you need is described in this Stackoverflow answer: [emberjs Ember.Select dynamic contentBinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899274/emberjs-ember-select-dynamic-contentbinding)

It has a JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/lifeinafolder/4fjC4/