# emberjs Ember.Select dynamic contentBinding

Tags: ember.js

I have some thing like this:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();


App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
    id: null,
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null,

    fullName: function() {
        return this.get('firstName') + " " + this.get('lastName');
    }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});

App.selectedPersonController = Ember.Object.create({
    person: null
});

App.selectedChildrenController = Ember.Object.create({
    person: null
});

App.peopleController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [
        App.Person.create({
        id: 1,
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe'
    }),
        App.Person.create({
        id: 2,
        firstName: 'Tom',
        lastName: 'Cruise'
    }),
        App.Person.create({
        id: 3,
        firstName: 'Peter',
        lastName: 'Pan'
    }),
        App.Person.create({
        id: 4,
        firstName: 'Sergey',
        lastName: 'Brin'
    })
        ]

});

App.childrenController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    children: [
        App.Person.create({
        person_id: 1,
        firstName: 'Scott',
        lastName: 'Hall'
    }),
        App.Person.create({
        person_id: 1,
        firstName: 'Jim',
        lastName: 'Can'
    }),
        App.Person.create({
        person_id: 2,
        firstName: 'Will',
        lastName: 'Smith'
    }),
        App.Person.create({
        person_id: 4,
        firstName: 'Bale',
        lastName: 'Ron'
    })
        ],
    active: function() {
        if (App.selectedPersonController.person) {
            return this.get("children").filterProperty("person_id", App.selectedPersonController.person.id);
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }.property("App.selectedPersonController.person").cacheable()

});


window.App.Select = Ember.Select.extend({
    contentChanged: function() {
        this.$().selectBox('destroy').selectBox();
    }.observes('content')

});
```

​and my view code is something like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{view window.App.Select
         contentBinding="App.peopleController"
         selectionBinding="App.selectedPersonController.person"
         optionLabelPath="content.fullName"
         optionValuePath="content.id"
         prompt="Pick a person:"}}

     {{view window.App.Select
         contentBinding="App.childrenController.active"
         selectionBinding="App.selectedChildrenController.person"
         optionLabelPath="content.fullName"
         optionValuePath="content.id"
         prompt="Pick a child:"}}

  <p>Selected: {{App.selectedPersonController.person.fullName}}
    (ID: {{App.selectedPersonController.person.id}})</p>

</script>
```

​I want my second window.App.Select to dynamically update depending on the selection in the first window.App.Select. I am using **contentBinding="App.childrenController.active"** for the second window.App.Select to make this work but what it does is that if I select a value in the person selectbox the child selectbox does not update, now when I select a different person from the person selectbox the child seletbox gets populated with the filtered values depending on my previous selection in the person select box.

Person selectbox -> select = John Doe (Nothing Happens)

Person selectbox -> select = Tom Cruise (Child select box gets filtered according to "John Doe" selection)

And so on.

Please see what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 3):

I've put everything together again, in an attempt to restore Rajat's dead link into a working jsbin, implementing this version of the chained, or dependent, select boxes using ember.js/1.0.0-rc3.

http://jsbin.com/ixogag/5/